# SonarQube: Improvement of Measure filter widgets

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

In SonarQube there is the possibility of using measure filters to look at all the files of a project or directory in a measure filter widget. Actual you must explicitly set the project , subproject or directory you are interested in in the 'Components Of' - criteria of the the measure filter, if you only want to see the files of the so configured resource. It would be nice if the widget can present all the data relevant to the selected resource (via selection out of view 'Favorite Components' in view 'My Account') like other widgets (e.g. Custom Measures widget), then you only have to create the filter once and not for each Project, subproject or Directory.  Is there a possibility now to define one measure filter which can be used in different kind of projects to render the files and the selected measures of the former selected favorite resource ? 
Eventually the measure filter concept can be extended in future SonarQube versions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, measure filters (along with their widgets and the customizable dashboards) will disappear in upcoming versions of SonarQube.

I know that this feature sounds powerful, but in fact it covers very few day-to-day use cases. Mainly, people use it to query the data in various ways - which is a not-so-frequent use case. SonarQube mainly targets:

- Developers who use it on a daily basis to track their incoming issues (what we call the leak) and make sure that they fix it as soon as possible to keep their code under control
- Tech Leads and project managers who track the overall evolution of their projects thanks to ratings
- Executives who want to keep an eye on project portfolios with higher indicators

This is why we are moving away from the kind of general-purpose usage of SonarQube that customizable dashboards, widgets and issue/measure filters could bring. Please read the blog post that I wrote on ["SonarQube 6.x series"](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-6-x-series-focused-and-efficient/) (especially the "User-needs oriented spaces") to know more about this move.